# How to convert images color space in Keras?

Tags: keras

I am feeding RGB color images to a Neural Network implemented with Keras. How can I have Keras convert the images to a different color space (e.g. YUV, Lab, or some grayscale)?

I tried with a `Lambda()` layer, but got an error:

`model.add(Lambda(lambda x: cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB), input_shape=(160, 320, 3)))`

gave me

`TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`

I believe the issue is that `x` is a Tensor, and I don't know how to convert it to something OpenCV accepts.

Even better, if I can have it done in the GPU instead. E.g. with Tensorflow I would use functions such as `tf.image.rgb_to_hsv()` and `tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale()`.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you convert the color space outside the model? Feels unnecessary to do it in the model.

Comment: By doing it in the model, it would run in the GPU, which is faster, and it would be used by training, validation, testing and actual classification the same way. However, I am not finding any way to do it in the computational graph with the current Keras API, will probably end up doing as you say.

Comment: use Lambda layer, but use tensorflow conversion inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import tensorflow, you can use the tf.image.rgb_to_hsv() function in the lambda:

```
def hsv_conversion(x):
    import tensorflow as tf    
    return tf.image.rgb_to_hsv(x)

model.add(Lambda(hsv_conversion, input_shape=(160, 320, 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to use opencv in an preprocessing layer using Keras lambda layers to ensure that all the preprocessing done on my images are the same whether training, testing or predicting. However I found that **you must use tensor operations on tensors**. So you're limited to simple arithmetic operations in your lambda and whatever tensor-operations you can find in keras.backend.