# cifar 100 data (50000, 32, 32, 3) shape change to (50000, 32, 32) shape

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, training-data

I have downloaded cifar100 data from tf.keras.datasets. How can i change data (50000, 32, 32, 3) shape to (50000, 32, 32) to training ?

is it possibe to train without changeing shape as well?

Comment: Cifar100 has RGB images so I am not sure what you mean by *changing shape to (50000, 32, 32)*. You need to add your model.

Comment: Do you mean converting RGB images to Grayscale ones? In that case, the following links may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836358/keras-rgb-to-grayscale and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale. Note that tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale outputs a tensor with channel size of 1, which can be dropped using `squeeze`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze

Answer (score 0):

You can train the model without changing the data shape from (50000, 32, 32, 3) to (50000, 32, 32).
You need to mention the `input_shape` with `RGB channel = 3` while defining the model for training as below:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
```

Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn) for more details on model training with **cifar10** dataset.